# Mudar a cor quando chegar em determinado número

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um teste aqui, e quando o sensorValor chegar a determinado valor, como exemplo usei o 5 ele mudasse a cor da tabela onde o mesmo está sendo escrito para verde, atualmente ela se encontra em vermelho dai superior a 5 o sensorValor ficária em verde e inferior a isso voltaria a ficar vermelha.

O bad_3 é a div criada para ficar na cor verde, e o contador_3 para ficar em vermelho.

Tentei nesse exemplo no script logo abaixo, porém não funcionou:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = 0;
    var testCounter = 0;
    var contaBotao = 0;
    var testEnable = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    setInterval(function() {
    $.get ("IOCounter_3.html", function(result) {
    $('#counter_3').text(result.trim());
    sensorValor = $('#counter_3').text();
});
});
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get ("IOCounter_4.html", function(result) {
    $('#counter_4').text(result.trim());
    sensorValor = $('#counter_4').text();
});
});
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get ("IOCounter_5.html", function(result) {
    $('#counter_5').text(result.trim());
    sensorValor = $('#counter_5').text();
});
});
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get ("IOCounter_6.html", function(result) {
    $('#counter_6').text(result.trim());
    sensorValor = $('#counter_6').text();
});
});
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get ("IOCounter_7.html", function(result) {
    $('#counter_7').text(result.trim());
    sensorValor = $('#counter_7').text();
});
});
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get ("IOCounter_8.html", function(result) {
    $('#counter_8').text(result.trim());
    sensorValor = $('#counter_8').text();
});
});
    $(".botaonibus").click(function(e) {
    $('#contador_3').show();
    $('#contador_4').show();
    $('#contador_5').show();
    $('#contador_6').show();
    $('#contador_7').show();
    $('#contador_8').show();
    $('.meubotao').hide();
    $('.ingles').hide();
    $('.port').hide();
    $('#counter_3').show();
    $('#counter_4').show();
    $('#counter_5').show();
    $('#counter_6').show();
    $('#counter_7').show();
    $('#counter_8').show();

    setInterval(function () {
      roundedValue = Math.round(parseFloat(sensorValor) * 100) / 100;
      if ((roundedValue >=5) && testEnable) {
        $('#bad_3').show();
        testEnable = false;
      }

      else if ((roundedValue <=3) && testEnable) {
        $('#contador_3').show();
        testEnable = false;
      }
    }, 50);

    var len = $('.testes1 div').length;
    // //Se for a primeira vez ele é 0 então não entrará, mas na segunda vez 
    //  ele entra no if e pega a div anterior "testCounter-1"
    if(len> testCounter) {
    if(contaBotao> 0) {
    $('.testes1 div').eq(testCounter - 1).hide();
    $('#contador_3').hide();
    $('#contador_4').hide();
    $('#contador_5').hide();
    $('#contador_6').hide();
    $('#contador_7').hide();
    $('#contador_8').hide();
    $('#counter_3').hide();
    $('#counter_4').hide();
    $('#counter_5').hide();
    $('#counter_6').hide();
    $('#counter_7').hide();
    $('#counter_8').hide();
}
    contaBotao++;
    $('.testes1 div').eq(testCounter).show();
    testCounter++;
    if(len == testCounter) {
    $('.botaonibus').hide(); //ultima etapa ja chegou
    $('.goback').show();
    $('#contador_3').hide();
    $('#counter_3').hide();
}
else {
    $('.botaonibus').html('Next Step');
    $('.botaonibus').addClass('proxEtapa1');
        }
      }
    });
});
```